# Why is docker exec combining STDERR and STDOUT streams

Tags: docker

Here's an example of outputting stderr using `docker exec`, and the output is sent to STDOUT.

```
$ docker exec -t 09b24cd7fa69 ls nosuchfile 1>docker.out 2>docker.err 
$ cat docker.out 
ls: cannot access 'nosuchfile': No such file or directory
$ cat docker.err 
$
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is in the `-t` flag. Without it STDOUT and STDERR work as expected.

Comment: *nod*. When you tell Docker to set up a TTY, both stdout and stderr are directed to that pseudo-TTY; so long as both FD 1 and 2 are directed there, there's no way to distinguish which individual file handle something was written through.